# gnome.h: How to install the Gnome development library

Tags: gnome, compiling

Colleagues, can you tell me how to install the Gnome library for development?

I use Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS x86_64, Kernel: 5.11.0-34-generic

I installed the Gtk+ library quite easily and compiled a few simple programs.
Now I want to use Gnome.

My program contains including the gnome.h header file:

```
#include <gnome.h>
```

Unfortunately, this file is missing from the system.

```
# find / -name gnome.h -print
find: ‘/run/user/1000/doc’: Acces denied
find: ‘/run/user/1000/gvfs’: Acces denied

#
```

I cannot figure out how I need to install the Gnome development library so that gnome.h and information for pkg-config appear on the system.

Please tell me how I can solve my problem.

Comment: I think `gnome.h` may be part of the deprecated [libgnomeui-dev](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libgnomeui-dev) package - see for example [libgnome and libgnomeui Must Die!](https://wiki.gnome.org/Attic/LibgnomeMustDie)

Comment: @Nmath I have added more information. I have nothing more to add.

Comment: @steeldriver I think so too. But if I give the command "apt install libgnomeui-dev", then in response they writes that such a library was not found.

Comment: @ogogon that's essentially what "deprecated" means - it was available in  the Ubuntu repository up to and including 18.04. Since you are using 20.04, it is not. You shouldn't be using it for new code.